# Import object declared inside __init__.py

Tags: python, python-module

I'm having trouble understanding how objects declared inside '__init__.py' are/should be imported to other files.

I have a directory structure like so

```
top/
 |
 |_lib/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ one.py
```

File contents are as follows

**lib/__init__.py**

```
a=object()
```

**lib/one.py**

```
from lib import a
```

Here is the problem. If I fire a python shell from `top` directory, the following command runs well

```
>>> from lib.one import a
```

However if I change directory to `top/lib` and fire a similar command in a new python shell, I get error.

```
>>>  from one import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "one.py", line 1, in <module>
  from lib import a
ImportError: No module named lib
```

Ofcourse, I can change `one.py` like so, that will make everything work.

```
from __init__ import a
```

But I'm really trying to understand, why import command works from `top` directory and not from `top/lib`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, I think it's best practice to have the data funnel up to `__init__.py` from the modules/subpackages rather than needing to rely on data from `__init__.py` in the surrounding modules.  In other words, `__init__.py` can use `one.py`, but `one.py` shouldn't use data/functions in `__init__.py`.

Now, to your question...

It works in `top` because python does a relative import (which is gone in python3.x IIRC, so don't depend on it ;-).  In other words, python looks in the current directory for a module or package name `lib` and it imports it.  That's all fine so far.  running `from lib.one import a` first imports `lib` (`__init__.py`) which works fine.  Then it imports `one` -- `lib` still imports ok from `one` because it's relative to your current working directory -- Not relative to the source file.

When you move into the `lib` directory, python can no longer find `lib` in the current directory making it not importable.  Note that with most packages, this is fixed by installing the package which puts it someplace that python can find it without it needing to be in the current directory.

Comment: That makes lot of sense. Thanks